# MVC jquery post to method working to id but not for string or list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some jquery to post to an MVC method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void MarkAsPaid(int id)
        {
            ...
        }
```

This worked fine with this jquery call:

```
$.post('/Invoice/MarkAsPaid/'+ invoiceId, function (data) {
                        ...
                    });
```

However how do I change this instead to send through a list of ids in string format eg. "1,4,5"?

I tried:

```
[HttpPost]
            public void MarkAsPaid(string ids)
            {
                ...
            }

    $.post('/Invoice/MarkAsPaid/'+ "1,4,5", function (data) {
                            ...
                        });
```

The ids comes through as null though.

I'm currently thinking how I'm actually passing the variables in the post doesn't look right at all and is probably why it isn't working. Also maybe it's because I've changed the type name in MarkAsPaid to ids rather than id.

Can someone please tell me how to do this? Passing them through in a list would also be an adequate solution.

Comment: I think json format should be a good solutions here.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $.post('/Invoice/MarkAsPaid/'+ encodeURI("1,4,5"), function (data) {
                            ...
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'1,4,5'
```

Just remove the Double quotes